# Open links from questions and answers in new tab

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hyperlinks

I need to open links from posts and answers in a new tab instead of the annoying in-place opening, without use of the `<Ctrl>` button or anything else just in ordinary way.

Comment: I wrote my userscript to open links in new tab and put it on stackapps - [StackExchange link newtaber](https://stackapps.com/questions/7803/stackexchange-link-newtaber-open-links-from-questions-and-answers-in-new-tab).

Comment: What do you mean by *"anything else just in ordinary way"*? Do you mean the ordinary way is to open in a new tab or that the ordinary way is to use something similar to Ctrl (e.g. right click and select *"Open Link in New Tab"*)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, english is not my native language and maybe I made mistake. I mean "the ordinary way is to open in a new tab" e.g. just by ordinary click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I did not find any sufficient solution of my problem I wrote a userscript which does what I want. If you have the same issue you can install it from my repository:
[StackExchange link newtaber](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts/raw/master/src/StackExchange_link_newtaber.user.js)

Installation instructions:

> 1. Install the userscript extension for your browser:
>
>    - Chrome:  [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
>    - Firefox: <del>[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)</del> [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/)
> 2. Go to [my userscript](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts) repository, open `StackExchange_link_newtaber.user.js` script and click `Raw` link - or simply click [here](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts/raw/master/src/StackExchange_link_newtaber.user.js))
> 3. Click `Install` in the your browser extension window

This script should work in all Stack Exchange sites.

#### Update

I finally moved this to [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/about) - [StackExchange link newtaber](https://stackapps.com/questions/7803/stackexchange-link-newtaber-open-links-from-questions-and-answers-in-new-tab).
Welcome.

Comment: testing https://www.google.com

Comment: It doesn't work for links in comments (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 58.0.2)

Comment: it works for me with links in comments including your comment above (openSuse Thumbleweed, Chrome 64). could you review errors in the Developer Tools and post here?

Comment: Hmm - it works now.

Comment: @DavidPostill ok, I'm very glad. I hope my script is useful for you.

Comment: I recommend posting this on https://stackapps.com.

Comment: I do not sure if userscript is suitable for stackapps but thank you I'll try

Comment: @PaolaCaptanovska There is one thing that need fixing. It breaks editing comments :/

Comment: yes, I discovered this bug today and have fixed it in version 0.3. what version do you use? just update it